# Even though I logged into docker from my terminal, I get a "requested access to the resource is denied" resource for FROM 3.11.0rc1-alpine3.16

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to docker compose up using a series of small dockerfiles containing Flask applications.

I type `sudo docker-compose up` and it gives the error:

```
sudo docker-compose up
Building rentCanada
Sending build context to Docker daemon  9.728kB
Step 1/10 : FROM 3.11.0rc1-alpine3.16
pull access denied for 3.11.0rc1-alpine3.16, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
ERROR: Service 'rentCanada' failed to build : Build failed
```

But I already logged in:

```
 sudo docker login
Authenticating with existing credentials...
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
```

So it isn't that, and in any case, I think it looks strange because [I am using a public image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python): `3.11.0rc1-alpine3.16`

Here is my Dockerfile for the failing service:

```
FROM 3.11.0rc1-alpine3.16
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
RUN pip install flask
RUN pip install requests
EXPOSE 8082
COPY . .
CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=8082"]
```

(all 3 services' Dockerfiles are almost identical except for the port)

This failed when I was using `3.10.6-bullseye` as well

Comment: You're missing the image name ("python"), you've only included the tag, try `FROM python:3.11.0rc1-alpine3.16`

Comment: beautiful! thanks, I'm a newb at Docker